# Алгоритм регистрации и авторизации через социальные сети

Tags: oauth, php, vkontakte-api, авторизация, регистрация

Добрый вечер.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать сабж. Что хранить в базе, что держать в куках и как организовать авторизацию. Можно без кода - на словах. На всякий случай - пишу на PHP.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пришёл новый чел, авторизуете его через ВК (см. [Виджет Авторизации](https://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=%C4%EE%EA%F3%EC%E5%ED%F2%E0%F6%E8%FF+%EA+%E2%E8%E4%E6%E5%F2%F3+%E0%E2%F2%EE%F0%E8%E7%E0%F6%E8%E8)), получая от ВК напрямую в ваш сервер подтверждение, что этот клиент действительно Вася с ID 12345. Генерите для Васи запись у себя в БД, в том числе некий уникальный ключ, а ему ставите куки с этим ключем.

В следующий раз придёт - если есть куки, соотв. записи в вашей БД - это видимо, Вася.

Comment: Все эти данные, получается, можно взять из открытого доступа и просто подобрать алгоритм шифрования уникального ключа - а затем и куки подменить. Первое правило криптографии: учитывать, что у злоумышленника уже имеется алгоритм шифрования. Я думал эта проблема более-менее решена, поэтому хотел узнать, как это всё делается.

Comment: Прочитайте же про виджет и протокол. Полученный ответ вы проверяете по цифровой подписи на основе секретного ключа вашего сайта в ВК.

А с куки надёжность приемлемая для большинства веб приложений. Даже если взять простейший вариант: в БД случайный набор символов в качестве "ключа", и в куки `md5()` от него, и ID пользователя. Простой перебор — весь арсенал взломщика, который займёт его на пару вечностей : )

    $randkey = md5( microtime(TRUE) . 'SecretServerKey'); // его в базу
    $cookie = $user_id . ':' . md5($randkey); // в куки

Comment: Этот способ очевиден, я думал, может есть что-то такое, чего я не нагуглил и о чём не слышал. Вопрос висит уже два дня, думаю уже бы заминусовали и тыкнули носом в ссылку какую-нибудь :) В общем - спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте на StackOverflow поинтересоваться ; )

Comment: Виджет авторизации ВК лучше не использовать. Он очень глючный.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь уже готовыми решениями, например http://ulogin.ru/constructor.php
На странице справки, в разделе "Настройки виджета" -> "Информация о пользователе" найдете все данные, которые можно выудить из соц сети про данного пользователя, от имени, почты, до пола и возраста (если конечно есть такие).
Дальше - как при обычной авторизации через логин форму - ставите куку после авторизации, и понеслась. Или делаете что-то типа авторегистрации (минимально необходимые данные уже ведь есть) и если чего-то нехватает, можете перебрасывать пользователя на профиль и пусть дозаполняет то, что осталось в неведении. При этом, раз пользователь фактически не вводит пароль, то можно ему сгенерить какой-нибудь достаточно стойкий из вида "!k2j$4#(Dk)543\bls"